# What does (meta property="og:title" content) mean?

Tags: seo

What is the purpose of using meta properties?  is it a good idea to implement it on my site?

Answer (score 1):

`meta property=“og:title”` is one of the open graph meta tags.

This properties define objects in a social graph. They are used by Facebook.

og:title stands for the title of your object as it should appear within the graph.

(Find more http://ogp.me/)